# How to use V8 JavaScript engine in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, v8

I have a Xamarin Forms application in which I have to call JavaScript and use its result. I've resolved it with JavaScriptCore on iOS and Chakra on Win10 (and I assume ChakraCore would work on Win8.1 as well), but I like to use the V8 JavaScript Engine on android. However I can't find how I can use it in Xamarin.

Is there even a way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the author.

https://github.com/web-atoms/xamarin-v8

Add NuGet Package

```
 <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.V8" Version="1.4.79" />
```

Code

```
  using(var context = new JSContext( /*Enable Debugging*/ true)) {

    // you can connect to dev tools by visiting url
     // devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9222/backend

  context["printf"] = context.CreateFunction(0, (c, a) => {
      // first parameter is context isself
      // second parameter is an array as IJSValue
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a[0].ToString());
       return c.Undefined;
  });

   // script location is useful for debugging
   context.Evaluate(scriptText, scriptLocation);

}
```